# Android App Crashes using AppCompatActivity API16

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing a simple android app with a webview that extends AppCompatActivity.
This is my app manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.appname">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

minSdkVersion:16
targetSdkVersion:24
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

The problem is when I test the app on my physical devices it runs with no errors on API18 and above. But when I try it on API16 the app crashes

```
E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
```

and if I change from AppCompatActivity to Activity the app runs fine on API16.
I have already tryed many solutions I found online, but none of them worked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: this problem is look like with your vector drawable(xml drawable).

Comment: will you please post your app gradle file please.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after updating the build tools